# Jenkins build Failed but all stages Succeeded

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline that all stages complete and report as Success but the overall build is marked as Failed.  This occurs every time a build is run.  Builds are run from start to finish without any "continue from last stage".  The jenkins version and plugins are all updated to current.

If I look at each stage it says "Success" in the hover-over (see screenshot).

What am I missing here?

[My Jenkinsfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qxm2GJlDFrCnYBIk7xsPGMHgEs80-L_C/view?usp=sharing)
[image]
[image]

EDIT 1: Adding blue ocean screenshot:
[image]

The end of the pipeline log file:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
Post stage
[Pipeline] junit
Recording test results
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] mail
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: FAILURE
```

EDIT 2: Added post section

Here is the end of the pipeline statement:

```
post {
    failure {
        mail to:    "$MAIL_NOTIFY",
        subject:    "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
        body:       "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}"
    }
}
```

EDIT 3: Removed post failure

If I remove the "post { failure { mail ... } }" section then the build completes successfully.  So the question is now... How do I fix this section to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the send email step is failing, can you try using:

```
environment {
            EMAIL_TO = 'someone@host.com'
        }
    post {
            failure {
                emailext body: 'Check console output at $BUILD_URL to view the results. \n\n ${CHANGES} \n\n -------------------------------------------------- \n${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=100, escapeHtml=false}', 
                        to: EMAIL_TO, 
                        subject: 'Build failed in Jenkins: $PROJECT_NAME - #$BUILD_NUMBER'
            }

        }
```

Comment: Yes that seems to work.  I don't get a Failure of the whole build with that code.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue . The reason was I used publishhtml , and the repot folder was missing , which threw error in console log , but stage passed (GREEN) and job showed RED (failed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the Console log of that job, though all the stages Succeded, there must be a step that is failing at last part.

Comment: I've checked every single stage and all say Success and there are no errors/failures in the logs.

Comment: can you provide your full console log? When using Pipeline, It's way better to use Blue Ocean plugin to see in which part it failed.

Comment: Probably something has failed in the post actions, like sending emails or you use log parser? This is also a common sight if a previous build with the same build number had failed and you deleted that build and reset the build number. The latter can be resolved by restarting Jenkins.

Comment: I forgot about Blue Ocean!  I opened that and it still doesn't show any obvious problem.  The pipeline log file is 4+ MB so I'm not posting it.  I did add the end of the log file to the post above.  The last line is "Finished: FAILURE".  I did a "grep FAIL log.txt" of the pipeline file and found nothing but my own code.

Comment: Then it might be at the" Declarative: Post Actions" what do you do there? it seems to send an email.. is it really sending it?

Comment: See EDIT 2 for the last actions in post {} at end of pipeline.  I basically send mail if the build fails.  At least that's the intention.  I do get the email being sent saying the build has failed.  So the mail send process is working.

Comment: Then the email is fine. Have you tried searching for ERROR or Fail words in the full console log? It's a kind of difficult to know what it may causing.. or unless you are setting a the var that jenkins use to know if the job success or fails.

Comment: If I comment out the "post { failure { mail ... } }" section then the build completes fine.  So that begs the question... what's wrong with this particular section?